# Number format exception Integer class java

Tags: java, logic, syntax-error

Simple problem really here is the code:

```
public class BlankClass
{

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        String string1 = new String("ABCD1234");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(string1);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ABCD1234"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

ABCD1234 Should equal 2,882,343,476 in base 10 which is smaller then 2^32 4,294,967,296 :\

But in this case:

```
public class BlankClass
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        System.out.println(2882343476);
        System.out.println(Math.pow(2, 32));
    }
}
```

Here is the error that gives:

```
BlankClass.java:6: error: integer number too large: 2882343476
    System.out.println(2882343476);
                       ^
1 error
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: "ABCD1234 Should equal 2,882,343,476" - in what way? What makes you think that `Integer.parseInt` accepts hex input? Is that what the documentation says? And what makes you think that an `int` is valid up to 2^32? (Hint: how would it represent negative numbers?)

Comment: -1 You should read the docs or search before asking. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because "ABCD1234" is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and also you didn't parse it in a hexadecimal way.
The following code works:

```
String string1 = new String("ABCD1234");
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(string1, 16));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a radix if you want to parse hex numbers:

```
String string1 = new String("ABCD");
int i = Integer.parseInt(string1, 16);
```

But you need to use a long anyway:

```
2882343476 0xABCD1234
2147483647 Integer.MAX
```

So that's your code:

```
String string1 = new String("ABCD1234");
long i = Long.parseLong(string1, 16);
```

See [Integer.MAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).